# Can you unmount Drive in Ubuntu's GUI?

Tags: mount, 16.04, nautilus

I do quality assurance of my fat32 drive based on the answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/288963/16920). 
I think *gparted* is not sufficient here. 
I cannot find an option by double clicking the drive for unmount. 
I would like to use GUI for such things to avoid mistakes in unmounting wrong drives or only a partion.

[image]

- In terminal, I would do `lsblk` for drive `/dev/sd*` and `umount /dev/sdb1` etc. But I really would like to avoid it if I can.

  ```
  masi@masi:~/Documents$ lsblk
  NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
  sda      8:0    0   113G  0 disk 
  ├─sda1   8:1    0     1M  0 part 
  ├─sda2   8:2    0 105.1G  0 part /
  └─sda3   8:3    0     8G  0 part [SWAP]
  sdb      8:16   1 119.9G  0 disk 
  └─sdb1   8:17   1 119.9G  0 part /media/masi/FAT32
  masi@masi:~/Documents$ umount sdb1
  umount: sdb1: No such file or directory
  masi@masi:~/Documents$ umount /dev/sdb1
  masi@masi:~/Documents$
  ```

  Complications

  ```
  masi@masi:~/Documents$ sudo fsck.vfat /dev/sdb1
  fsck.fat 3.0.28 (2015-05-16)
  0x41: Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt.
  1) Remove dirty bit
  2) No action
  ?
  ```

  where you see that I made a mistake somewhere.
- Use Ubuntu's Eject (= Safe Eject). I do `sudo fsck.vfat /dev/sdb1` which does not seem be promising.

  ```
  masi@masi:~/Documents$ sudo fsck.vfat /dev/sdb1
  fsck.fat 3.0.28 (2015-05-16)
  open: No such file or directory
  ```

System: Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I think it is eject?

Comment: Can you do it from gparted?

Comment: I honestly don't know :-( I work more on the server side of things.

Comment: I guess Canonical implemented a safe-eject function (eject button to the right of drive's name). Thunar in Xubuntu xenial still uses the old way (unmount + eject functions). Try a different file manger and see what happens.

Comment: Eject works on my systems using Ubuntu 16.04 AND Ubuntu Gnome 14.04.  For both USB drives, and partitions on my other HDD's.  I usually just click the Eject icon.

Comment: @Masi: Thunar, Nemo, PCManFM, Caja, Dolphin, etc. Thunar and PCManFM are still using the classical way (right-click -> unmount, then right-click -> eject). I know cause i use them everyday. Nemo and Caja are from LinuxMint, i guess they should have that option too.

Comment: @Masi From what I understand, you're trying to run these commands after you've run the Eject command.  In which case the output makes sense.  Is this a USB device?  If so, it will be powered down and no longer accessible unless you unplug it and plug it back in.

Comment: With the safely remove device that will flush the buffers before eject, you can always run the command `sync` before you run `umount /dev/sdb1` just so the buffers have been flushed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Ubuntu 12.04, ejecting a USB drive or partition has the same effect as "Safely Remove" (with Nautilus).

You can verify this with some USB devices that have some kind of power indicator on them.  The device will sync, unmount if not busy, and then power down, i.e., the power/status light will turn off.  To remount or reuse a powered down USB device, you need to unplug it and plug it back in.  A partition can simply be re-accessed.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, there is no "Unmount" option because the device must sync before unmounting, because it's FAT formatted. Meanwhile, disks in formats like NTFS or EXT don't need to sync before unmount.

Comment: @wjandrea no, I do not think that this is the case. What happens is that they "collapsed" the various options (safely remove drive, eject, umount) to just one that do the safest thing every time. (And yes, the unplug/plug thing is nasty.)

Comment: @Rmano But FAT devices do need to sync before unmounting, right? So it would be bad design to put an option that might destroy data into the Nautilus UI.

Comment: They sync and buffers are written before unmounting and powering off.

Comment: @wjandrea all block device is cached so any device needs sync.

Comment: It would be nice if you could check the quality assurance for any FAT32 disc after your proposal. Any code example is also welcome.

Comment: If you're worried about data loss, you could create a new blank file , write a single character into it, save and then immediately press eject.  After remounting, if the file is there as well as the character you typed, then it is syncing properly before unmounting. A single character would definitely stay in the buffer so that's a good test. The eject will also fail if the drive is being used to avoid corruption.  In terminal, cd to your removable drive, type `while true; do ls; done` and then try to eject the disk.  It should say it's busy.